# Visualising a raster PostgreSQL table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, postgresql

I have imported a raster tif image into PostgreSQL with this command:

```
raster2pgsql -s 32643 -I -M filepath.tif -F -t 100x100 public.databassename > filepath.sql
```

And imported the output SQL file inside the PostgreSQL database running this:

```
psql -U postgres -d databasename -f filepath.sql
```

After connecting to this database in QGIS, I am not able to visualise the tif image due to missing geometry content. Please help me out to visualise the tif raster imagery in QGIS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In QGIS 2.6.1, go to menu `Database->DB Manager->DB Manager`, set the database connection and you will see the raster table. You can drag and drop it or right click and select `Add to canvas`.

From your description of the problem, you are using the regular "Add PostGIS Layers", which will not show your raster table, since it is for vectors and alphanumeric tables.

Comment: What about Leaflet ? Do you know a way to add postgres rasters to Leaflet Map ?